# query remove records from database but table row not fadeout that one

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter-3

Controller as follows:

```
        public function deleteCategory()
         {
        if(adminLoggedIn())
        {
        if($this->input->is_ajax_request())
        {
            $data['cId'] = $this->input->post('id',true);
            $cId = $this->input->post('text',true);
            if(!empty($cId) && isset($cId))
            {
                $catId=$this->encryption->decrypt($cId);

                $old_Img = $this->AdminLogin->getCategoryImage($catId);
                if(!empty($old_Img) && count($old_Img) == 1)
                {
                    $reaImage = $old_Img[0]['cDp'];
                }
                $delCatId = $this->AdminLogin->categoryDelete($catId);
                if($delCatId)
                {

                    if(!empty($reaImage) && isset($reaImage))
                    {
                        if(file_exists('./upload/admin/category/'.$reaImage))
                        {
                            @unlink('./upload/admin/category/'.$reaImage);
                        }
                    }
                    $data['return'] = "true";
                    $data['message'] = "Successfully Deleted";
                    echo json_encode($data);
                    // set_flashdata('alert-danger','You have successfully deleted Category','admin/allcategories');

                }
                else
                {
                    $data['return'] = "true";
                    $data['message'] = "Not Successfully Deleted";
                    echo json_encode($data);
                    // set_flashdata('alert-danger','You cant allowed delete this category','admin/allcategories');

                }
            }
            else
            {
                set_flashdata('alert-danger','You cant allowed delete this category','admin/allcategories');
            }
        }
        else
        {
            set_flashdata('alert-danger','Something Went wrong . Please try again later','admin/allcategories');
        }
        

    }
    else
    {
        set_flashdata('alert-danger','Please login first and then try again later','admin/login');

    }

}
```

jquery as follows:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
       $('.delcat').click(function(){
          var id = $(this).data('id');
          var text = $(this).data('text');
          $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: burl+'admin/deleteCategory',
              data: {id:id,text:text},
              dataType: 'JSON',
              success: function(data) {
                // console.log(data);
                 var deleteData = $.parseJSON(data);;
                 // console.log(deleteData);
                 if($deleteData.return == "true")
                 {
                    console.log("hii");
                    $('.error').text(deleteData.message);
                    $('.cat'+id).fadeOut();
                 }
                 else if($deleteData.return == "false")
                 {
                    console.log("hii1");
                    $('.error').text(deleteData.message);
                 }
                 else
                 {
                    console.log("hii2");
                    $('.error').text("Something Went wrong");
                 }
              },

              error: function($data) {
                 $('.error').text("Something Went wrong");
              },
             
           });
```

});
});

html as follows

```
  <tr class="cat<?php echo $value->cId; ?>">
                    <td><?php echo $key+1;?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $value->cName;?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $value->cDate;?></td>
                    <td><a href="<?php echo base_url('admin/editCategory/'.$value->cId)?>" class="btn btn-info">Edit</a></td>
                    <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-danger delcat" data-id="<?php echo $value->cId;?>" data-text="<?php echo $this->encryption->encrypt($value->cId);?>">Delete</a></td>
                  </tr>

              <?php  

                }  
              }    

            ?>
              </tbody>
              </table>
            <p><?php echo $links; ?></p>
         </div>
```

Can i get this solutions as soon as possible. I m stuck into this thing.
I'm using this code in Codeigniter framework, Following code delete record from database, but table row not removed or fadeout... please check code, and let me know, how to fix this code.

Comment: Please read:  
[**Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question?**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest), in order to obtain faster answers? - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and it is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       $('.delcat').click(function(){
          var id = $(this).data('id');
          var text = $(this).data('text');
         var $ele = $(this).parent().parent();    //add this line.

          $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: burl+'admin/deleteCategory',
              data: {id:id,text:text},
              dataType: 'JSON',
              success: function(data) {
                // console.log(data);
                 var deleteData = $.parseJSON(data);;
                 // console.log(deleteData);
                 if($deleteData.return == "true")
                 {
                    console.log("hii");
                    $('.error').text(deleteData.message);
                  $ele.fadeOut().remove();           //add this line.
                 }
                 }
                 })
                 }
                 });
```

Comment: No its not working . its not fadeout. Deleting from database but in UI need to page refresh. its not going fadeout.